# How to solve "Undeclared identifier error" in "if" block?

Tags: c++, matlab

I am creating `vector` in building `mex` file. I need to creat a `vector<vector<int>>` which size is according to the input variable. The creating or declaring part is in a `if` block. I need to use this variable outside the `if`. Then it has an error "undeclared identifier". I found I should pre-define the variable. But I don't know the size in this way. Do I need to define a global variable? Or any other suggestion? My code is below.

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray* plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray* prhs[])
{
int i;
if ( i == 0) // if block
    {
        mwSize Num = mxGetNumberOfElements(prhs[i]);
        vector<vector<int>> V0(Num);
    }
cout << V0.size()<<"\n"; // error
}
```

This is a simplified example code. I really need the `if` block. I think the problem is from the variable domain. But I have not figure out a good way to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

You intuition is correct. The lifetime of `V0` ends at the closing curly bracket of the enclosing `if`. The object is destroyed and the name isn't visible in the outer scope.

You could solve the problem by moving it outside the `if`.

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray* plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray* prhs[])
{
    vector<vector<int>> V0;
    int i; // hey, this is uninitialized!
    if (i == 0) // if block
    {
        mwSize Num = mxGetNumberOfElements(prhs[i]);
        V0.resize(Num);
    }
    cout << V0.size() << "\n"; // the vector is visible here
}
```

Comment: Could also be worth pointing out that the uninitialized thing is actually really bad since the `if (i == 0)` will then be undefined behaviour

Comment: @Tas You're right but they did say it's "simplified example code". I'm assuming their actual code is more complete.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Thank you for relating the `V.resize()`.This is what I need.

Answer (score 1):

The vector `V0` is declared in your `if` block, and it only exists within that scope. You are accessing it outside of that scope.

Also, you left the parens off the call to `size()`.

Answer (score 0):

`vector< vector<int>> V0(Num);` This is declared inside the if, you are trying to use it outside of `if`. That's the problem.

Comment: C++11 fixed that actually

Comment: Sorry, this is not the error line. I think my complier could allow this.

Comment: Oh I see, you declare the the vector inside the `if` then trying to call it outside of if. That's the problem.